# Displaying some of the database data in .NET MVC textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database

I have to display 9 fields with labels.
6 of them are hardcoded in the database (because they should be non-editable) and the rest of 3 are user inputs.
The codes are attached herewith.
Please help!

**My model is:**

```
public partial class User
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("User Name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter your User Name!")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your Password!")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public string LoginErrorMessage { get; set; }

        /* My changes */
        [DisplayName("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Father's Name")]
        public string FatherName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("CNIC (without dashes)")]
        public int CNIC { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Address")]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Line Manager")]
        public string LineManager { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Department")]
        public string Department { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Designation")]
        public string Designation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**My controller:**

```
namespace MVC_Login_6Dec.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var data = db.Users.ToList();
            return View();
        }

        /* My Changes */

            private LoginDatabaseEntities db = new LoginDatabaseEntities();

            public ActionResult GetList()
            {
                var userData = (from user in db.Users select user).ToList();
                return View(userData);
            }

            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult GetList(User model)
            {
                var data = db.Users.ToList();
                return View(data);
            }
    }
}
```

**My View:**

```
@model MVC_Login_6Dec.Models.User
@{
    Layout = null;
    if (Session["userID"] == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Login/Index");
    }
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div"> 
        <h1>Employee Details</h1>
        <div>
            <h4>UserName: @Session["userName"].ToString()</h4>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="@Url.Action("Logout","Login")">Logout</a>
        </div>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("GetList", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.Name)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Name)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.FatherName)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.FatherName)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.CNIC)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.CNIC)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.Address)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Address)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.LineManager)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.LineManager)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.Department)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Department)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.Designation)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Designation)</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The data is not shown in the fields and they are empty.

**My Output:**

[Output Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8QeV.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screenshot of the output doesn't show the route (URL) for the page you are displaying, so I'm not sure which controller action you are calling. However, your view requires a MVC_Login_6Dec.Models.User object, and none of your controller actions are passing a single User object to the view. Let's say you have a view called "Edit", you would need an action that did something like this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int UserId)
{
     var user = db.Users.Where(x => x.UserID == UserId).FirstOrDefault()
     return View(user);
}
```

You would then call this action by going to http://localhost/home/edit/{the id}. You also need to make sure your App_Start\RouteConfig.cs is configured in the "normal" way:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", 
            id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

If you put a debug breakpoint inside this controller action, you will also be able to inspect the user object to see if your Database Entities object is configured properly and returning data.